# How I can get index from each element from json and output as array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have this json code:

```
 "genres":[{"id":28,"name":"Action"},{"id":53,"name":"Thriller"},{"id":878,"name":"Science Fiction"}]
```

How I can get in Javascript only id from each like:

```
['28', '53', '878']
```

I need this values to set selected in select2

```
$('#gen').select2().select2('val', ['28', '53', '878']);
```

Thank you!

Comment: `$('#gen').select2().select2('val', data.genres.map(el => String(el.id))); `

Comment: The ids need to be strings. Will that work @Nick?

Comment: It will now.. :)

Comment: @Nick I have write `$('#gen').select2().select2('val', json.map(el => String(el.id)));` but I get selected only first value that is 28 why?

Comment: Not sure. There may be something wrong with the structure of your JSON? You can see here it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-yalow-esvdh?file=/src/index.js:248-265

Comment: Thank you mate, I have resolved with this: `$('#gen').select2().val(json.map(el => String(el.id))).trigger('change');`

Answer (score 0):

```
var filter = genres.map(x => x.id)
$('#gen').select2().select2('val', filter);
```